# Lightning input does not display picklist

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When a picklist field is rendered via `apex:inputfield` it automatically displays the picklist entries available for that field in UI.

In my lightning component I tried doing the same with `lightning:input` but for some reason it just shows a text box without displaying the picklist entries.

Lightning Component Markup

Genre__c is a picklist field.

```
<aura:component controller="ShowClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="AAShow" type="Show__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Show__c'}"/>
    <lightning:input label="Name: " name="LIUI_ShowName" value="{!v.AAShow.ShowName__c}" />
    <lightning:input label="Rating: " name="LIUI_ShowRating" value="{!v.AAShow.Rating__c}" />
    <lightning:input label="Genre :" name="LIUI_ShowGenre" value="{!v.AAShow.Genre__c}"/> 
    <lightning:buttonIcon onclick="{!c.fLIUI_Button_Clicked}" iconName="utility:save" variant="bare" size="large" alternativeText="Save" iconClass="dark"/> 
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lightning:input is a generic input, and defaults to a "text" input. If you want to bind to a field in an sObject, use lightning:inputField instead. Otherwise, if you want to roll your own field, use lightning:select (you'll need to retrieve the picklist values from the server).

Answer (score 2):

A `lightning:inputField` component displays an editable field based on the field type. For example, if fieldName references a date value, then a date field with a date picker is rendered. If fieldName references a picklist, then a dropdown menu displays values based on your record types. This component requires API version 42.0 and later.

use this component with lightning:recordEditForm and pass in a record ID and object API name.

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="fieleName__c" />
```